# PWM IRF510 Mosfet Current very low

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pwm

I have a PWM circuit board as shown below that is connected to a water canister. The purpose is to generate hydrogen bubbles. The setup is working but the production of bubbles is very low. The current draw for the entire setup is also very low at about 25ma. The current should be at around 2A and producing a ton more hydrogen bubbles.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

There are two metal strips in the water acting as anode and cathode. I am running the signal at 750Kh, 50% duty cycle. The voltage is supplied by a 48V DC power supply. I operate anywhere from 15-40v.

This is what the signal looks like at the Gate of the Mosfet from the Mosfet driver:

[image: Gate Driver]

This is what the signal looks like at the Drain:

[image: Drain]

The rising edge is slowish and a little rough. And as I mentioned there is very little current flow. The mosfet is cold to the touch.

I'm not sure what to start looking at next???

Comment: What if you bypass the MOSFET and connect the black electrode directly to ground. Do you get more current?

Comment: I wonder if you realize that doing water electrolysis at 48V is very inefficient since the electrolysis requires a minimum of 1.229V and the amount of gas produced depends only on the current, not the voltage.

Comment: Have you added any chemicals (eg salt) to the water?

Comment: I bypassed the entire board and the current is less, about half, but the bubble production is about the same...low.

Well, this setup is a little different. I'm not using an electrolyte. I'm experimenting. This is sort of a piezo like type of setup . Yes, current flow is the problem...very little.

Comment: @user3511513 how big are the electrodes and how far apart are they?

Comment: The electrodes are flat metal strips 2" x 4" and about 1.5" apart. I have played with closer distances and bubble production increases a little but current stays very low.